# Calculating $\iint_D(x^3+y^3)dxdy$ for $D=\{(x,y)~|~0\le x,y\le1\}$

Tags: integration

How do I calculate
$\iint_D(x^3+y^3)dxdy$ for $D=\{(x,y)~|~0\le x,y\le1\}$?

Specifically what I don't get is what do I let the upper bound of $x$ and lower bound of $y$ be?

Comment: I believe the notation means that both $x$ and $y$ are between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted it as $(0\leq x),(y\leq 1)$. I think it would be more likely to be written as $0\leq x\text{ and }y\leq 1$ in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $0\le x,y\le1$ is often the lazy form of $0\le x\le1$, and $0\le y\le 1$. In my opinion it is needlessly confusing.

Comment: $0\leq a,b,c,d,e,f,g\leq1$. And now? I think it is not only less writing, it is also more clear and easier to understand.

Comment: @EricS. "$0\ge a,b,c,d,e,f,g\ge1$" looks pretty confusing to me :P

Comment: It might be misinterpreted as $(0\leq x),(y\leq 1)$.

Comment: @EricS. but more seriously, that one isn't the one I'm complaining about. That ambiguity is resolved because there is a third variable: There is only one thing $0\le a,b,c\le 1$ could plausibly mean, while there are two things $0\le x,y\le1$ could plausibly mean.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt, haha, I can't argue with that, it is indeed a matter of personal choice. However, what do you think of $0\leq a\leq1$ and $0\leq b\leq1$ and $0\leq c\leq1$ and $0\leq d\leq1$ and $0\leq e\leq1$ and $0\leq f\leq1$ and $0\leq g\leq1$?

Comment: @EricS. : I agree with Peter completely. Don't muddle his statement. As written, the notation *is* lazy and needlessly confusing. If you really were using seven variables in this way, you might have done a better job by calling them $a_k$ and stating that $0\leq a_k \leq 1$ for each $k$.

Comment: @both, okay, no more muddling then :p  What is confusing about it?

Comment: @EricS. I'm fine with the notation $0\le a,b,c,d,e,f,g\le1$, I just am not okay with it when there are two variables in particular. The issue is, does it mean $0\le x\le1$ and $0\le y\le1$, or does it mean $0\le x$ and $y\le 1$. The difficulty comes with what the comma means. "$0\le x,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,y\le1$" seems different, no?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt, Ah okay. I wasn't trying to be funny or sarcastic, I've just never seen $0\leq x,y\leq1$ to indicate $0\leq x$ and $y\leq1$, so that's why I don't find it confusing.

Comment: Anyway, $0\leq x,y\leq1$ is commonly accepted to mean **only** $0\leq x\leq1$ and $0\leq y\leq1$, maybe that takes away your confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Your integral can also be written as $\int_0^1{\int_0^1{(x^3+y^3)dx}dy}$. Do you know how to proceed now?